# String processing error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to analyze the a series of passwords for frequency. My script is working with other input media, however it appears that there's some bad characters in my current data set. How can I get around the "bad" data?

```
import re
import collections 
words = re.findall('\w+', open('rockyou.txt').read().lower())
a=collections.Counter(words).most_common(50)
for word in a:
     print(word)
```

I then get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "shakecount.py", line 3, in <module>
    words = re.findall('\w+', open('rockyou.txt').read().lower().ASCII)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/codecs.py", line 300, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 5079963: invalid continuation byte
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code doesn't exactly match your error (I assume an attempt at debugging?), but your text file isn't `UTF-8`.

You need to manually specify an encoding, with my best guess being `latin-1`:

```
words = re.findall('\w+', open('rockyou.txt', encoding='latin-1').read().lower())
```

if you want to continue despite errors, you can pass `errors='ignore'` or `errors='replace'` to `open`.

Comment: The above was helpful but didn't ultimately solve the issue, I ran in to more greek errors (I'm new to programming). I ended up opening the word list in a text editor and resaved as a utf-8 format which then worked. Thanks to agf for your help!

Comment: @AlphaTested If you don't know the encoding, another way would be to use [chardet](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) to detect it.